# What are the endpoint and namespace of liferay's users Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, liferay

I have to consume the User's CRUD SOAP Webservice that liferay exposes. How can I know which is this service's endpoint? What's the address of the wsdl given the address where the portal stands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.example.com/tunnel-web/axis - If you're not accessing from localhost (e.g. x.x.x.x), you need to allow access for the client in one of these:

```
tunnel.servlet.hosts.allowed=127.0.0.1,SERVER_IP,x.x.x.x
axis.servlet.hosts.allowed=127.0.0.1,SERVER_IP,x.x.x.x
```

You'll find the WSDL there (add these settings to your portal-ext.properties)